# Does MonetDB's code contain the X100(VectorWise) 's research?

Tags: database, monetdb

Since X100 project has been commercialized into the Actian/VectorWise company. I wonder if it's technology remains in MonetDB's code base.

In paper 'MonetDB: Two Decades of Research in Column-oriented Database Architectures', it is said that both fundamental and high risk projects are fully materialized within the MonetDB kernel and are disseminated as open source code together with the rest
of the MonetDB code family. Does it mean that all those rearch project have there code in MonetDB code base?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The open-source code base of MonetDB is completely disjoint from the Action/Vectorwise code base, despite the fact that many of the X100 ideas were inspired by earlier versions of the MonetDB code base. 
The Action/Vectorwise code is further optimized for vectorised (vulcano-style) execution and embedded in the old Ingres code base.